# Deleting a specific set of elements from a complex nested structure in matlab efficiently

Tags: matlab, structure, bigdata

I have a complex nested structure in MATLAB:
a.b.c, a.b.d, a.b.e...a.b.p
a has 4 elements, b has 90 and c has a variable number of elements
I want to delete for example: the 5 element of c,d,e,f,....p for a particular b(i)
How can I do that in one command or most efficiently without having to write down

```
a(1).b(i).c(5)=[];....
a(1).b(i).p(5)=[];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not possible without looping through the elements of the substructure *unless* you want to apply the change to all elements of a given level

---

**For a selection of elements**
Solution for looping through a subset of elements, using dynamic field names

```
ai=1;                 % first level index
bi=2;                 % second level index
rem=[1,5]             % elements to remove

for ci='c':'p'        % field names to change
    a(ai).b(bi).(ci)(rem)=[];
end
```

---

**For all elements**
Example to remove 1st and 5th column from all a(1).b(2)

```
ia=1;  % a index
ib=2;  % b index
rem=[1,5]; % columns to remove
a(ia).b(ib)=structfun(@(a)a(setdiff(1:end,rem)),a(ia).b(ib),'unifo',0)
```

note: is doesn't remove the elements but overwrites the modified parts of the structure omitting the elements to be removed

what the line does

```
a(ia).b(ib)=structfun(@(a)a(setdiff(1:end,rem)),a(ia).b(ib),'unifo',0)

                            setdiff(1:end,rem)            % elements not in rem
                      @(a)a(                  )           % get these elements of
            structfun(                         ,a(ia).b(ib)   % this sub array
a(ia).b(ib)=                                                  % and overwrite it
```

finally `,'unifo',0)` tells matlab the out put of `@(a)a(setdiff(1:end,rem))` is not a single value i.e. still a vector

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that passing a character variable to define a structure name was possible. I have done a slight modification though...instead of c,d,e,f..p I have large parameter names... so i created a structure of them p{1}='c', p{2}='d' and  looped through p{i}..that works for me